# How can I divide a string with split() into separate strings with 15 items at each index?

Tags: java, parsing

Normally with `split()` it will divide a whole string by one regex.

So if I take `String objects= "door,cat,house,trash";`
and do `objects.split(",")` it will split it into an array of `String[] objects= {"door","cat","house","trash"};` as you probably know.

But I don't want to separate it with *every* comma. I want to separate it with every 15th item. So my list would have `String[] objects= {"door,cat,house,trash...obj15","obj1,obj2,obj3...obj15"};`

Does that make sense? How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split()` is not good for that. Use a `find()` loop instead.

*Demo (Java 4+)*

```
String input = "door,cat,house,trash,e5,f6,g7,h8,i9,j10,k11,l12,m13,n14,o15,p16,q17,r18,s19,t20";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?=.)((?:[^,]*,){0,4}[^,]*),?");
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (Matcher m = p.matcher(input); m.find(); )
    result.add(m.group(1));

for (String s : result)
    System.out.println('"' + s + '"');
```

*Demo (Java 9+)*

```
String input = "door,cat,house,trash,e5,f6,g7,h8,i9,j10,k11,l12,m13,n14,o15,p16,q17,r18,s19,t20";

String[] result = Pattern.compile("(?=.)((?:[^,]*,){0,4}[^,]*),?").matcher(input)
                  .results().map(m -> m.group(1)).toArray(String[]::new);

Arrays.stream(result).forEach(s -> System.out.println('"' + s + '"'));
```

*Output*

```
"door,cat,house,trash,e5"
"f6,g7,h8,i9,j10"
"k11,l12,m13,n14,o15"
"p16,q17,r18,s19,t20"
```

You should of course change `{0,4}` to `{0,14}` if you want 15 values per block.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers suggest using complicated regular expressions. I would avoid that. Use Guava to partition the split string into groups of fifteen, and join each group back up with commas:

```
String[] objects = "door,cat,trash,house,...";
List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList(objects.split(","));
String[] result = Lists.partition(list, 15).stream()
    .map(each -> String.join(",", each))
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score -1):

First thing that came to mind is try splitting them with split(",") then loop through them and add any other symbol in the 15th place other than , (e.g $).
Then you split by that (e.g split("$"))

I don't know how effective it is but here you go.

Answer (score -2):

Try the following regex pattern `[a-z]+(,[a-z]+){14}`. This will match
a list of 15 comma separated words. If I were you, I would switch to using the provided `Matcher` and `Pattern` classes to find this regex pattern (instead of using `split`).

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-z]+(,[a-z]+){14}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("dog,door,cat,other,etc...");

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: Input `"door,cat,house,trash,e5,f6,g7,h8,i9,j10,k11,l12,m13,n14,o15,p16,q17,r18,s19,t20"` ... Nope, not working.

Comment: I was more suggesting to use Regex `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes... Clearly, if your elements hold numbers, this pattern wouldn't work. However coming up with the correct pattern wouldn't be too hard (As seen in @Andreas's answer)

Comment: Coming up with the regex *is* the question. Besides, simply changing `[a-z]` to `[a-z0-9]` still wouldn't work for that input, because splitting 20 values into 15-value chunks leaves only 5 values for the last chunk, and this regex can't handle that. It's not as simple as you make it out to be. *(and yes, I can see my own answer)*

Comment: I didn't say `[a-z0-9]` was the right answer. Also, `[^,]+(,[^,]+){0,14}` I believe would be a clearer Regex pattern than the one in your answer.

Comment: You are assuming there are no empty values, e.g. `door,cat,,,house,trash`. Once you make the value optional, the regex becomes more complex (again). As I already mentioned, the *regex* is issue in the question, so an answer that shows a non-working regex is simply not a *useful* answer.